# Encontrar el número más cercano, remplazar y mostrar el reemplazado y reemplazo y posicion

Tags: array, c#-8.0

Tengo que crear un arreglo de 25 elementos (números aleatorios) en C#

Entonces debo pedir un número cualquiera que se va a buscar dentro del arreglo, si se encuentra dicho número se muestra "el valor se encontró" si no, se busca al número menor más cercano y se reemplaza, muestra el remplazo, el nuevo y la posición a ocupar.

Ya hice la primer parte pero no sé cómo hacer lo otro ayuda por favor

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declaracion de varibales
        int find = 0;
        int[] elementos;

        //ARREGLO Y LLENADO
        elementos = arreglo();            

        //LEEDATO
        find = leedato();

        //IMPRIME EXISTENCIA
        Console.WriteLine(buscarexistencia(elementos, find));


        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    //LEE VALORR  BUSCAR
    public static int leedato ()
    {
        int find = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el valor que quiere buscar");
        find = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return find;
    }
    //inicializa un arreglo y se llena con valores aleatorios
    public static int[] arreglo()
    {
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        int[] elementos = new int[25];
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            elementos[i] = aleatorio.Next(0, 100);
        }
        return elementos;
    }
    //EVALUA LA CONDICION "SI EL DATO A BUSCAR SE ENCUENTRA EN EL ARREGLO"
    public static Boolean buscarexistencia (int[]elemtos, int find)
    {
        Boolean answer = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < elemtos.Length; i++)
        {
            if (elemtos[i] == find)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("VALOR ENCONTRADO");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No especifica bien la forma en que debe reemplazarse, mostrarse el reemplazo, el nuevo y la posición a ocupar.

Sin embargo, puede encontrar el número menor más cercano o igual al número requerido de la siguiente forma:

```
private static int searchTheNumber(int[] numbers, int target)
{
    // Buscamos el número menor más cercano o igual al número requerido
    int result = (
        from num in numbers
        let diff = Math.Abs(target - num)
        orderby diff
        select num
    ).First();

    return result;
}
```

De manera que su código con la capacidad de generar los 25 números alteatorios, buscar el número menor más cercano o igual y mostrarlo en consola quedaría así:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Pedimos al usuario que ingrese el número a buscar
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el valor que quiere buscar:");
        int target = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] randomNumbers = generateRandomNumbers();
        int number = searchTheNumber(randomNumbers, target);

        // Si el valor encontrado es igual al solicitado
        // mostramos el mensaje de valor encontrado
        if (target == number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Valor encontrado: " + number);
        }
    }

    private static int[] generateRandomNumbers()
    {
        // Generaramos el array con los 25 números aleatorios
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100;
        int count = 50;

        var random = new Random();
        var numbers = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = random.Next(min, max);
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    private static int searchTheNumber(int[] numbers, int target)
    {
        // Buscamos el número menor más cercano o igual al número requerido
        int result = (
            from num in numbers
            let diff = Math.Abs(target - num)
            orderby diff
            select num
        ).First();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: En un vector de 25 elementos, se desea buscar un dato que será leído. Diseñe un 
programa que imprima el mensaje: “VALOR ENCONTRADO”, si en efecto el valor buscado ya se encuentra entre los elementos, y la posición o subíndice donde se 
encontró la primera vez.
Si el valor no se encuentra, se debe sustituir el valor menor por el buscado, imprimiendo 
el elemento que sale del vector y la posición que ocupaba. Ese sería el problema original

Comment: En efecto la parte que no me queda del todo clara es eso de que si el valor no se encuentra, se debe sustituir el valor menor por el buscado, o sea, donde se debe sustituir?